# ChakraUI: How to use extendTheme to change body background colour

Tags: chakra-ui

How do I use extendTheme to change the background colour of my website. So far I've tried this:

```
const theme = extendTheme({
  body: {
    bg: "#e5ecff",
  },
```

I've also tried this:

```
const theme = extendTheme({
  colors: {
    bg: "#e5ecff",
  },
```

Neither have worked. I'm sure it's a small issue but I can't seem to find the necessary documentation on the chakraUI docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Chakra UI global styles can be overridden by extending the theme's `styles.global`. Without the rest of the code as context, it looks like the code above is accessing `global.body.bg` instead of `styles.global.body.bg`.

**To customize the Chakra UI global styles:**

1. Define `styles.global` overrides with extendTheme.
2. Specify the customized `theme` on the `ChakraProvider` or the `ChakraBaseProvider`.

---

I've included an example below that overrides the default light/dark background and color. The example uses a function that returns a style object, but it can also be specified as a style object directly. For examples of both, see [Customizing Global Styles](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/customize-theme#customizing-global-styles) in the Chakra UI documentation.

---

**App.js** / [Live example on replit](https://replit.com/@toolsareplit/chakra-ui-customize-global-styles)

```
import { extendTheme, ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import {mode} from "@chakra-ui/theme-tools";

const theme = extendTheme({
  styles: {
    global: (props) => ({
      body: {
        bg: mode('blue.50', 'blue.900')(props),
        color: mode('blue.900', 'blue.50')(props)
      }
    })
  }
 });

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
        {/* Your Content Here */}
    </ChakraProvider>
  )
};
```

---